# Repeat effect over n length

Tags: html, css

I have this `<div>` with a `radial-gradient` on it, however I don't want it to be over all the `<div>` but rather I'd like it to go some amount down and then repeat.

[So to be clear I don't want the gradient to stretch over the div like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/botAJ.png)
[But rather repeat across the div at a certain height like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E25SP.png)

Comment: Provide us with part of the code so we can understand what you are actually trying to do. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a selector, class or id to your div.

```
.container{
  height: 500px;
  background: red; 
  background: radial-gradient(red, yellow);
  width: 100%px;
}

.content{
  position:absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 35%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background: 
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Please Ignore the positions, and etc...
Only focus in the class container and content. That the css of gradient background only affect the div that has the class.

Check this: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramon_schmidt/y6xed81q/4/)